Adding items to ForEach and animate the items below nicely so it doesn't jump
I'm trying to get this to animate nicely when I add elements to my array.
Currently the button jumps down after the foreach elements are added.

Here's my code:
import SwiftUI

class ForEachAnimationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var array: [String] = []
    var count = 5
    
    init() {
        array = (0..<count).map({ "Element \($0)" })
    }
    
    func addMore() {
        let newItems = (count..<count+5).map({ "Element \($0)" })
        array.append(contentsOf: newItems)
    }
}

struct ForEachAnimationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ForEachAnimationViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(viewModel.array, id: \.self) { element in
                Text(element)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    viewModel.addMore()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ForEachAnimationView(viewModel: ForEachAnimationViewModel())
}



View struct should be your view model and use state for a source of truth, you don't need any objects.

There is a problem with the way that new entries are being added to the array. The variable count is not being updated when more entries are added, so this results in errors being shown in the console about duplicate ids. One way to fix would be to change the function addMore to base the new ids on the existing count:
func addMore() {
    let count = array.count
    let newItems = (count..<count+5).map({ "Element \($0)" })
    array.append(contentsOf: newItems)
}

The animation can then be improved with these changes:

add an .animation modifier to the ScrollView
add a .transition modifier to the Text items
set a minWidth on the Text, to avoid wrapping issues when the width of one row is larger than the width of the previous row.

struct ForEachAnimationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ForEachAnimationViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(viewModel.array, id: \.self) { element in
                Text(element)
                    .frame(minWidth: 200)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
            Button("Button") {
                viewModel.addMore()
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: viewModel.array)
    }
}

You can try other types of transition, but if you want to see the rows appear one by one, it would be better to add them one by one instead of in batches of 5.


Not only this solved my issue but also gave me great insight on how animations work. I really appreciate it :)
